# The limit ratio of two Markov Chain Probability

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, st.statistics, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose there are two given SDE in $\mathbb{R}^d$:
$$
\begin{align}
   \left\{
\begin{aligned}
dX_t&=\begin{bmatrix}-\nabla V(X_t)+2\beta^{-1}v_F^\theta(X_t)\end{bmatrix}dt+\sqrt{2\beta^{-1}}dW_t,&X_0\in\partial A. \\
dY_t&=(-\nabla V(Y_t)+2\beta^{-1} v_F^\theta(Y_t)-2\beta^{-1}v_B^\phi(Y_t,t))dt\\&+\sqrt{2\beta^{-1}}d\tilde W_t,&Y_0\in\partial B.
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{align}
$$
where $A,B$ are given sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and $dW_t,d\tilde W_t$ are forward and backward Wiener Process respectively.
I can discretize them as two Markov Chains:
$$\begin{align}
   \left\{
\begin{aligned}
X_{t+\Delta t}&=X_t+\begin{bmatrix}-\nabla V(X_t)+2\beta^{-1}v_F^\theta(X_t)\end{bmatrix}\Delta t+\sqrt{2\beta^{-1}}\epsilon_t,&X_0\in\partial A. \\
Y_{t+\Delta t}&=Y_t+(-\nabla V(Y_t)+2\beta^{-1} v_F^\theta(Y_t)-2\beta^{-1}v_B^\phi(Y_t,t))\Delta t\\&+\sqrt{2\beta^{-1}}\tilde\epsilon_t,&Y_0\in\partial B.
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{align}$$
In the discrete case, for any given trajectory, I can calculate the following ratio:
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{\prod_{t=0}^{T}P_F(X_t|X_{t-\Delta t};\theta)}{\prod_{t=0}^T P_B(Y_{t}|Y_{t-\Delta t};\theta,\phi)}\\
=&\exp\sum_{t=0}^T\log\frac{P_F(X_t|X_{t-\Delta t};\theta)}{P_B(Y_t|Y_{t-\Delta t};\theta,\phi)}
\end{align}
$$
where $P_F,P_B$ are the transition probability of the two processes.
Here is my question:

1. Given any smooth curve $\varphi(t)$, is it possible to make a similar argument like the ratio above as $\Delta t\rightarrow 0$?
2. I have considered a few approaches, such as the Girsanov Transform and Onsager-Machlup function. If my target is to compare the probability of $P_F$ and $P_B$ on the curve $\varphi(t)$ and try to minimize the discrepancy, what is the naturalest way to extend?
   Thanks in advance for any suggestions.